# Policy on duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, support

What is the policy on duplicate answers? 
I was a few examples of questions for which there are 2 answers that look remarkably similar (if not the same).
For example these (but there are others):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10907/146
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19571/146

The answers were posted a few months apart so is not a case of who was faster by a few seconds.
Both the answers above practically say the same thing.
Are these answers allowed or should be flagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ideally we get more than one answer per question (it's a key metric in the SE world), but in the case of a true duplicate there is no value added. These should be removed or converted to a comment (as I had already done with the example you posted).